# rails embed has_one relation to a single database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let say I have a model that represents a Car (with some attributes).
I deffine a second model named wheel that contains the current wheel presure and diameter.
wheel: presure: int, diameter: int
Each car has 4 wheels.

**Simple solution** (not the desired one)

I create a Car model and a Wheel models. The wheel has a relation belongs_to Car, and the car has 4 has_one relations.

**What I want**

I don't want to have a Wheel ActiveRecord. I don't need to get all the wheels, etc. I want to store the wheels of a car in the same table as the car.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using postgres, look up arrays.

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero What you don't understand? I want something like http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Embeddable in rails